# How to navigate the directory structure of a Drupal site?

Tags: drupal

I am trying to add a page from an ASP.NET MVC site as an Iframe to a Drupal site but have been unable to locate the files within the Drupal directory structure that contain the actual site markup. Logging into the admin panel only gives me the page content. There is no markup.

I downloaded the entire contents of the FTP site and did a text search on several text snippets and CSS classes but I get no results except CSS files.

I had a similar exercise in Wordpress and those files were in a "themes" subfolder. No such luck here!

Where in the world is the site markup (the PHP or HTML files?) being hidden?

Answer (score 0):

You need to know which theme you are actually using. Navigate to /admin/appearance to figure that out.

It could be in these folders:

- /themes
- /sites/all/themes